# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call with error: Login Required

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, custom-function

I made a script using the [advanced service API Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). It's working fine when we stay into the app script GUI :

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function GetListOfDrivesName() {
  const ALL_AVALIBLE_DRIVE = Drive.Drives.list();
  return ALL_AVALIBLE_DRIVE.items.map(driveData => driveData = driveData.name)
}
```

However, when it's called from cell into Google Sheet we got an error

[image]

Error message is like below : `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.drives.list failed with error: Login Required.`

I guess it's some authentification & authorisation to ask before using the sheet.

Unfortuantly I have no idea how to request that ! I read [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) but it's sound like it will be asked promptly.
In addition, trigger have been added for this function but it neither worked

Any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I believe you can't call Drive.API from a custom function. It needs a workaround. For example you can make a custom menu (or button) and run the function from the menu/button. Or you can use the installable trigger `onEdit()` which will run the function as soon as you edit some cells on the sheet (or click on a checkbox, etc).

Comment: You may also have problems with this `Custom function arguments must be deterministic. That is, built-in spreadsheet functions that return a different result each time they calculate — such as NOW() or RAND() — are not allowed as arguments to a custom function. If a custom function tries to return a value based on one of these volatile built-in functions, it will display Loading... indefinitely.` which is found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi [@Yuri Khristich](/users/14265469/yuri-khristich)  you were right, using ui is a good work around , code turn up to work corectly

```js
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('[FM Script for G Drive]') 
  .addItem('test','showAvaillableDrive')
  .addToUi(); 
}
function showAvaillableDrive(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var resultat = ui.prompt(GetListOfDrivesName())
}
function GetListOfDrivesName() {
  const ALL_AVALIBLE_DRIVE = Drive.Drives.list();
  return ALL_AVALIBLE_DRIVE.items.map(driveData => driveData = driveData.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments you can build a menu over the Sheet and run it to write down Drive files that I own.

I have this custom [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0XHYqzFEJXJGl9VfyW9mfB2iIo__U4k12b_eb1Dpz0/edit#gid=0) where you can run the "Drive" function over "Adv Menu"

[image]

I automatically get the information of the Sheet and get a list of my Drive files:

```js
function onOpen () {
var ui= SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Adv Menu').addItem('Drive', 'getMyFilesFromDrive').addToUi();
}


function getMyFilesFromDrive() {
 var myFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners');
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Files");
 sheet.clear();
 var rows = [];
 rows.push(["ID", "Name", "Url"]);
 while(myFiles.hasNext()) {
   var file = myFiles.next();
   if(file != null) {
     rows.push([file.getId(), file.getName(), file.getUrl()]);
   }
 }
 sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,3).setValues(rows);
}
```

It would also write it directly to my Sheet. Feel free to review it and use it.

You can also Draw a button (Inserting a Google Drawing) over the Sheet and assign a script:

[image]

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus